# Why should I not give null a meaning?

Tags: java, null

I was reading [Tom Hawtin - tackline's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) the other day and I read this commandment:

> Please don't give nulls a meaning. Throw an NPE.

And I wondered two things regarding the first sentence: **how** any **why**?

First, the why. Why?

Second, the how. Let me give an example:

```
BigDecimal sales = ...;
BigDecimal cost = ...;
BigDecimal profit = sales.subtract(cost);
// Profit Margin = profit / sales
BigDecimal profitMargin = profit.divide(sales, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Here, we are calculating profit margin. Yet sometimes, `sales` will be 0. So, in that case:

```
BigDecimal profitMargin = sales.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ? null : profit.divide(sales, 20, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

We say that the `profitMargin` is `null` when there are no sales. This makes sense, right? Is there a better solution? Maybe you could argue that the profit margin is zero when there are no sales, but that's not entirely accurate. It could also be argued that zero sales gives you an infinite profit margin. But neither zero nor infinity accurately describes the zero-sales profit margin. ***Undefined*** works best. Which is precisely what `null` communicates.

This is one of many instances where I could imagine `null` having a very useful meaning that communicates a lot.

Am I misunderstanding the commandment? How would you handle the above situation without `null` ??

Comment: This seems more like something that would go on [Programmers SE](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/), because it doesn't directly deal with code and is more the conceptual side of programming. Perhaps flag your question and ask a mod to migrate it? It's a good question, though, in my opinion.

Comment: I think it's a philosophical issue...when you handle a NPE you are giving it a sense to that null value, also in the case where you check if(foo != null), in the context of your program this can have a  meaning as in: "this value is still null so i better do something else first and check again later.." but that doesn't mean that null is a value per se...

Comment: This may be helpful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/are-null-references-really-a-bad-thing In any case it's a matter of philosophy, as already stated by boolean.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [programmers.se]

Comment: I think it says "please read about [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)". Programmers indeed better place for this question *after* reading at least the pattern description .

Comment: I think he meant "don't give null alternative meanings", besides its usual meaning of "undefined".